# Mock Service Worker with Gatsby.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, msw, ssg

i'm using Mirage.js to fake api call's but mirage is causing some issues on our Gatsby project.

i had the idea of using with Mock Service Worker(MSW) instead.

i'm receiving an error when using `setupWorker`:

> [MSW] Failed to execute `setupWorker` in a non-browser environment. consider using `setupServer` for Node.js environment instead.

i tried using `setupServer`, but received errors from webpack

> ERROR #98124 Generating development JavaScript bundle failed

i'm not using it on Jest, its just for normal API calls

it possible to use MSW with Gatsby? i scrolled through the docs, but didn't find anything related to Gatsby.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying to integrate Mock Service Worker (MSW) into gatsby and think I finally found something that works...

Add the msw initialization into gatsby-browser.js:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  require("./src/mocks")
}
```